# I want withdraw from BitPay and send USD to bank account in Puerto Rico. I reside in Argentina. Is that possible?

Tags: sell-bitcoins, withdrawal, argentina

I want to withdraw/sell bitcoins that I have on my BitPay wallet. I need to transfer the results USD to account in Puerto Rico. I reside in Argentina.

I have already tried with Skirll, but does not allow Puerto Rico bank account.

Comment: If a US Exchange does not let you withdraw into your PR USA account, have a look at Wise used to be TransferWise

Answer (score 1):

You might need to list them for sale on a site like Coinbase (?) to convert them to USD. Then you would use your PR account to deposit the funds into. From there its a regular bank transaction of USD to Argentina or wherever.